Invertibility of an integral matrix expression
Given $A:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, $x\mapsto A(x)$ invertible for all $x$. In particular, it is known that $$A(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x)$$ with $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, continuously differentiable and $f(0) = 0$.
Show that
$$T(x) := \int_0^1 A(\sigma x) d\sigma $$ is invertible for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$.

False for $n \ge 2$. consider the case $A(x)$ are rotation matrices about some fixed axis with angle $|x|$, $T(x)$ will be degenerate when $|x|$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$ (other than $x = 0$).

I have edited the post with more information that may be relevant. It would really surprise me if this is not true, as it is required for the known solution of a bigger problem.

I think this is not true: First note that
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n: ~ T(x)x= \int_0^1 f'(\sigma x)x d\sigma = \int_0^1 \frac{d}{d\sigma}f(\sigma x) d\sigma = f(x)-f(0)=f(x).
$$
Now consider the function
$$
f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, \quad f(x,y)= {e^x\cos(y)-1 \choose e^x\sin(y)}.
$$
Then $\det (f'(x,y)) = e^{2x}$, hence $f'(x,y)$ is invertible for each $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Now
$$
T(0,2\pi){0 \choose 2\pi} = f(0,2\pi)={0 \choose 0}.
$$
Hence $T(0,2\pi)$ is not invertible.
